# is it OK to include own questions on CV?

Tags: cv

I was re-writing my CV and I thought that it could be a good idea to include the general/ultimate questions that "drive me to do science" or in particular "the kind of science I want to work in".

I don't want to make this personal. I would like to know if this kind of questions are acceptable/desirable or not a good idea.

I am a little bit prone to Biology questions because that's my area but I would love to have this question edited with other areas questions (example for physics: How do particles X and Y interact when condition=Z?)

**Independent Examples I can think of:**

- How do we learn?
- What drives animal instinct?
- How does an ecosystem work and fluctuates?
- How do plants deal with stress factors?
- Which is the origin of the cell?

I know that this might be quite naive/text book questions. However, I also believe that the eagerness to answer them is what really drives science forward.

**UPDATE**

I believe that the best/most used place to put these questions is the Statement of Purpose, or any other type of "motivation letter". I've found that many CV templates free available have an area dedicated for "Career Goal" or something equivalent. My understanding is that this is a brief place where you must include the most important part of what you would develop in a longer text. Also, when you send your CV (to a PI for example) you don't send a motivation letter with it. They are most used for application to universities and grant proposals.

Comment: That would fit well under research interests.

Comment: rplease see my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always a little risky to put "ultimate" questions on your CV -- often they're questions that everyone else has as well and that people don't know how to answer. You risk coming across as naive or even pretentious because you're effectively trying to associate yourself in people's minds with hard problems that you don't (at least right now) know how to solve. It's much better to stick to (a) things that you've done, (b) things that you're working on right now, (c) achievable things that you want to work on and that you have some specific ideas about.

Basically, being eager and keen to work on things is great, making your CV focus on your eagerness to do things rather than your ability to do them is not so great.

It's clearly important to say what you want to work on, but the goal is to say it in a calm, measured way that makes it sound plausible to everybody else.

Answer (score 14):

Ignoring exactly where you would put questions (e.g., CV or SoP), your example questions are inappropriate everywhere. They are such broad, unanswerable questions that they tell the reader little about you. The combination of questions makes the already broad even worse. If you are going to put questions/topics that interest you, they need to be specific enough, and ideally well thought out enough that they tell something abut you.

Instead of "how do we learn", maybe something like "in associative learning how does the saliency of the unconditional stimulus affect learning outcomes", if that is what you are interested in.

Comment: I get the point my CV questions look like the one you've written, I tried to avoid too technical questions in order to reach more  people into the relevant issue (whether or not is a good idea to include them). Also, I provided examples of different biological areas, clearly I'm not interested in unraveling the principles of plant biology AND the mysterious human mind, they were just two random examples.

Comment: Also, the "general kind of questions" are the things you might encounter in any lab webpage. Such as "What are the physiological mechanisms at the basis of fear and anxiety ?"

Comment: @MatiasAndina: They're more appropriate on a lab webpage because they're the goals for an entire group, usually articulated by a professor with a serious track record in the field. They sound less pretentious coming from someone with 20 years' experience, a couple of hundred papers and some prizes - people like that are expected to articulate their vision for the field.